# how to create a csv file with text links in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv

I see many NPM packages that write csv files, but I can't find anywhere documentation to create a hyperlink inside the csv.

I'm assuming that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, instead of writing the text, do this:

```
=HYPERLINK("URL_HERE", "TEXT_HERE")
```